# StreamElements Namespace

Tags: c#, xml

What is the namespace for `StreamElements` in C# 3.5?

Comment: Looking around, it doesn't look like that is a framework class or method. There's an implementation here though: http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/streaming-into-linq-to-xml-using-c-custom-iterators-and-xmlreader/

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking about the [System.Xml.Linq.XStreamingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement.aspx) class?